# React Too many re-renders. useEffect + useState + axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect, use-state

I´m new to react so I guess I haven't understood properly how the use effect and useStates works to prevent this error. I tried already to set the states in the array of useEffect to render only on the change but no success as well.
I´m trying to build dynamic forms configurations from a knack app (no code database app creator). So the end result would be a config I can use to render the form.
Below is a sample of my code.

```
const [fields, setObject] = useState([]);
const [groups, setGroup] = useState();
const [fieldGroupConfig, setFieldGroupConfig] = useState();
const [formConfig, setFormConfig] = useState();


useEffect(() => {

    axios.get(KnackUrl('entityDefinitions-ObjectBased', "object_4"), { headers: KnackHeaders() })
        .then(response => {
            setObject(response.data.object.fields)
        })


    axios.get(KnackUrl('getMultiple-ObjectBased', "object_31"), { headers: KnackHeaders() })
        .then(response => {
            setGroup(response.data.records)
        })

    axios.get(KnackUrl('getMultiple-ObjectBased', "object_32"), { headers: KnackHeaders() })
        .then(response => {
            setFieldGroupConfig(response.data.records)
        })
 
}, [])



if(groups && fieldGroupConfig && fields){
    groups.forEach((group) => {
        group.fields = [];
        fieldGroupConfig.forEach((fieldGroup) => {
          if (fieldGroup.field_333_raw[0].id === group.id) {
            fields.forEach((field) => {
              if (fieldGroup.field_330 === field.key) {
                group.fields.push(field);
              }
            });
          }
        });
    });
    setFormConfig(groups);
    
}
console.log('group prepared =>', formConfig);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are updating the state in useEffect which force the component to rerender. You can read more about lifecycle here https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Your `groups.map` sets the form config every iteration and you're throwing away the results of the `map`. While I'm not sure what all of this achieves, I assume you want to store the result of the `map` once in state. Never abuse `map` to produce side effects or as `forEach` or `filter`.

Comment: @ggorlen you were totally right about the setState being inside the map function, I changed it and also tried with forEach but still having the same result. (I updated the code above). What I want to achieve is to put in a state the result of the combination of all of the other states.